# Join another table and same table

Tags: mysql, sql

need your help here
I've been working on this query for a day lol

I have 2 tables

table Users

[image]

and table payroll_variable

[image]

My goals here to Join table users with 2 or more table payroll_variable like this

[image]

This is what I do so far :

```
      SELECT  DISTINCT
                u.id_user,
                u.first_name,
                u.last_name,
                pv.year,
                pv.base_salary,
                CASE
                    WHEN pv.month = 'January' THEN pv.total_salary
                    ELSE NULL
                END as 'January',
                CASE
                    WHEN pv1.month = 'February' THEN pv1.total_salary
                    ELSE NULL
                END as 'February'
        FROM payroll_variable pv
        INNER JOIN users u ON u.id_user = pv.id_user
        INNER JOIN payroll_variable pv1 ON  pv1.id_user = pv.id_user
        WHERE pv.status != 'submit'
```

And this the wrong result from my query

[image]

The problem is that , i just want to show every user with only one loop like my goals, and don't mind my WHERE clause , it's just for flag-ing

Comment: so what is the problem which you are facing now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'd changed name of two fields in my query i.e. month and year to payroll_month and payroll_year.

Here is the query that give you desired output

```
Select u.id_user, u.first_name, u.last_name, pv.payroll_year, pv.base_salary,
sum(IF(pv.payroll_month = 'January', pv.total_salary, 0)) as 'January',
sum(IF(pv.payroll_month = 'February', pv.total_salary, 0)) as 'February',
sum(IF(pv.payroll_month = 'March', pv.total_salary, 0)) as 'March',
sum(IF(pv.payroll_month = 'April', pv.total_salary, 0)) as 'April',
sum(IF(pv.payroll_month = 'May', pv.total_salary, 0)) as 'May',
sum(IF(pv.payroll_month = 'June', pv.total_salary, 0)) as 'June',
sum(IF(pv.payroll_month = 'July', pv.total_salary, 0)) as 'July',
sum(IF(pv.payroll_month = 'August', pv.total_salary, 0)) as 'August',
sum(IF(pv.payroll_month = 'September', pv.total_salary, 0)) as 'September',
sum(IF(pv.payroll_month = 'October', pv.total_salary, 0)) as 'October',
sum(IF(pv.payroll_month = 'November', pv.total_salary, 0)) as 'November',
sum(IF(pv.payroll_month = 'December', pv.total_salary, 0)) as 'December'
from users u join payroll_variable pv using(id_user)
group by u.id_user
```

[And sample output as in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28Cjj.png)

Comment: @SuluhDamarGrahita did you checked query? and just add before group by WHERE pv.status != 'submit' I forget to put it in my query.

Comment: Hey , thank you so much that's solved the problem. Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @SuluhDamarGrahita I am glad that it solved your problem. But it looks like you have marked wrong answer as correct answer.

Comment: The solution given by @Lajos Arpad  have some basic issues.
Edited query will create error as it left join users u with payroll_variable pv but in query salary fields references jan.total_salary and feb.total_salary which are no where defined. I think Jan and Feb reference to table alias. And in that case what if we need 12 months salary calculation? Joining same table again and again 12 times? This query become more complex and also resource hungry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not ensure that you have a record when there was no payment in either january or february and also, you do not ensure that you have a single record for each logical pair of january and february for the same user. You will need to use `LEFT JOIN` to ensure you have a row for each user and you will need to ensure that you have a single row for each logical tuples. I do not understand the logic behind your `where` condition, so I might be wrong there. I assume that a single record is stored for january or february if there was any payment:

```
  SELECT  DISTINCT
            u.id_user,
            u.first_name,
            u.last_name,
            pv.year as year,
            pv.base_salary,
            CASE
                WHEN pv.month = 'January' THEN pv.total_salary
                ELSE 0
            END as January,
            CASE
                WHEN pv.month = 'February' THEN pv.total_salary
                ELSE 0
            END as February,
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN payroll_variable jan ON u.id_user = jan.id_user
    LEFT JOIN payroll_variable feb ON  feb.id_user = u.id_user
    WHERE jan.status <> 'submit' and feb.status <> 'submit' and (not (jan.id_user is null) or not (feb.id_user is null))
```

This code is not tested and it is possible that I misunderstood your intention.

EDIT

In order to group your results by users, you will need to use group by:

```
select id_user, first_name, last_name, max(t.year), max(base_salary), sum(January) as January, sum(February) as February
from (
      SELECT
                u.id_user,
                u.first_name,
                u.last_name,
                min(pv.year) as year,
                min(pv.base_salary) as base_salary,
                sum(case when pv.payroll_month = 'January' then pv.total_salary else 0 end) as January,
                sum(case when pv.payroll_month = 'February' then pv.total_salary else 0 end) as February
        FROM users u
        LEFT JOIN payroll_variable pv ON u.id_user = pv.id_user) t
        group by t.id_user, t.first_name, t.last_name
```

Comment: Hey , thank you for your response. I've tried your answer but showing similar result to my code earlier. The problem i faced is that the query's loop the result i didn't want and i tried to get rid that un-necesary loop, and for payment doesn't matter if that is null . btw i updated my post to show the problem

Comment: @SuluhDamarGrahita I think I understand your problem now. Before I edit my answer I have a question: What if a user has two different not null values for January and/or February?

Comment: Thats fine as long as the result only one per user

Comment: @SuluhDamarGrahita I have edited my answer. It is not a tested code, if there are any problems, please let me know.

Comment: @SuluhDamarGrahita you are welcome. If my answer solved your problem, then you might consider marking it as the correct answer.